# ajax multi file upload module - How to add delete function?

Tags: ajax, upload

I want to have a file-by-file delete function when dragging and dropping files in the upload module developed with ajax. I don't know what to do.

I implemented deleting from the list when I click the del button on the list, but when I send it, the deleted file is also sent.
It's probably deleted from the list, but it doesn't appear in the drag and drop box, but it seems to remain.

[image]

```js
  /*
   * Some helper functions to work with our UI and keep our code cleaner
   */

// Adds an entry to our debug area
function ui_add_log(message, color)
{
  var d = new Date();

  var dateString = (('0' + d.getHours())).slice(-2) + ':' +
    (('0' + d.getMinutes())).slice(-2) + ':' +
    (('0' + d.getSeconds())).slice(-2);

  color = (typeof color === 'undefined' ? 'muted' : color);

  var template = $('#debug-template').text();
  template = template.replace('%%date%%', dateString);
  template = template.replace('%%message%%', message);
  template = template.replace('%%color%%', color);
  
  $('#debug').find('li.empty').fadeOut(); // remove the 'no messages yet'
  $('#debug').prepend(template);
}

// Creates a new file and add it to our list
function ui_multi_add_file(id, file)
{
  var template = $('#files-template').text();
  template = template.replace('%%filename%%', file.name);
  template = $(template);
  template.prop('id', 'uploaderFile' + id);
  template.data('file-id', id);

  $('#files').find('li.empty').fadeOut(); // remove the 'no files yet'   
  $('#files').prepend(template);
}

// Changes the status messages on our list
function ui_multi_update_file_status(id, status, message)
{
  $('#uploaderFile' + id).find('span').html(message).prop('class', 'status text-' + status);
}

// Updates a file progress, depending on the parameters it may animate it or change the color.
function ui_multi_update_file_progress(id, percent, color, active)
{
  color = (typeof color === 'undefined' ? false : color);
  active = (typeof active === 'undefined' ? true : active);

  var bar = $('#uploaderFile' + id).find('div.progress-bar');

  bar.width(percent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
  bar.toggleClass('progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated', active);

  if (percent === 0){
    bar.html('');
  } else {
    bar.html(percent + '%');
  }

  if (color !== false){
    bar.removeClass('bg-success bg-info bg-warning bg-danger');
    bar.addClass('bg-' + color);
  }
}
```

```css
/* 
    A couple styles to make the demo page look good
 */
body {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
hr {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
#files {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    min-height: 320px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #files {
        min-height: 0;
    }
}
#debug {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 180px;  
}

.dm-uploader {
    border: 0.25rem dashed #A5A5C7;
    text-align: center;
}
.dm-uploader.active {
    border-color: red;

    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>jQuery Ajax File Uploader Widget</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="../dist/css/jquery.dm-uploader.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <main role="main" class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          
          <!-- Our markup, the important part here! -->
          <div id="drag-and-drop-zone" class="dm-uploader p-5">
            <h3 class="mb-5 mt-5 text-muted">Drag &amp; drop files here</h3>

            <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-5">
                <span>Open the file Browser</span>
                <input type="file" title='Click to add Files' />
            </div>
          </div><!-- /uploader -->
        </div>      
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-header">
              File List
            </div>
            <font size="2">
            <ul class="list-unstyled p-2 d-flex flex-column col" id="files" style="height: 250px; overflow-x:hidden">
              <li class="text-muted text-center empty">No files selected.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /file list -->

    <div class="mt-2">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnApiStart">
            <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Start
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnApiCancel">
            <i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop
        </a>
    </div>

    </main> <!-- /container -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../dist/js/jquery.dm-uploader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="demo-config.js"></script>

    <!-- File item template -->
    <script type="text/html" id="files-template">
      <li class="media">
        <div class="media-body mb-1">
          <p class="mb-2">
            <strong>%%filename%%</strong> - Status: <span class="text-muted">Waiting</span> <span style="cursor:pointer; color:red;" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();">(del)</span>
          </p>
          <div class="progress mb-2">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-primary" 
              role="progressbar"
              style="width: 0%" 
              aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="mt-1 mb-1" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </script>

    <!-- Debug item template -->
    <script type="text/html" id="debug-template">
      <li class="list-group-item text-%%color%%"><strong>%%date%%</strong>: %%message%%</li>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```